# C# Singleton Thread-safe variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

I have referred to Jon Skeet's article here (http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx), the sixth version.

However, I have some private variables that I want initialized once, and be used by methods in this supposedly singleton class. I initialized them in the private constructor, but soon found out, that they are null when invoking the methods, in a multi-threaded scenario (*Task.Run*).

When debugging, I observed that the private constructor doesn't called twice (which should be) when I call out for an "Instance", and so I assume that my private variables, shouldn't be null at that point in time already (succeeding "Instance" calls).

Any idea on how should I declare, initialize, and use these variables?

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    // my private variables
    private readonly string _plantCode;

    private Singleton()
    {
       var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
       string _plantCode = appSettings["PlantCode"] ?? "Not Found";
    }

    public SomeMethod() 
    {
      var temp = _plantCode; // <== _plantCode becomes null here!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
string _plantCode = appSettings["PlantCode"] ?? "Not Found";
```

That isn't assigning to the instance variable - it's declaring a new *local* variable. You just want:

```
_plantCode = appSettings["PlantCode"] ?? "Not Found";
```

(This would happen with the same code in a normal class, by the way - it has nothing to do with the fact that it's a singleton.)

Comment: Ughhh... This is what you get when still working as the New Year approaches. Anyway thanks!!!